# tsconfig custom paths are not working even with /*

Tags: typescript, react-native

I can't seem to get these custom paths in tsconfig.json I always get the error like

`Cannot find module '@data/interfaces' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I even added the /* on every declaration of the path as I found in other posts, but that doesn't seem to do the trick

This is my tsconfig

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@lottie/*": ["assets/lottie/*"],
      "@components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@context/*": ["context/*"],
      "@data*": ["data/*"],
      "@features/*": ["features/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"],
      "@locales/*": ["locales/*"],
      "@navigators/*": ["navigators/*"],
      "@services/*": ["services/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["utils/*"],
      "@accounting/*": ["features/accounting/*"],
      "@auth/*": ["features/auth/*"],
      "@home/*": ["features/home/*"],
      "@production/*": ["features/production/*"],
      "@repair/*": ["features/repair/*"],
      "@sale/*": ["features/sale/*"],
      "@scanner/*": ["features/scanner/*"],
      "@settings/*": ["features/settings/*"],
      "@warehouse/*": ["features/warehouse/*"],
    },
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to reset VSC, thats all it took